# How to trade bitcoin in bitcoin?

Tags: exchanges, trading

I'm curious about how to trade bitcoin in bitcoins. I want to do this because it squares the gains (and losses) from crypto. I'm not intending on doing this with leverage for safety reasons. So, what I mean is like (but don't say this) Bit-MEX (for the most part): the price doubles, and the amount of money in real dollars quadruples. This is like trading on x times leverage where x is the current price divided by the entry price with insignificant to no liquidation risk. I would prefer it to be for Coinbase because that is what is popular.

Example based on past data:

BTC price is $3,150 in Dec 2018...0.05 BTC bought for under $200.

BTC price is $13,400 in Jun 2019...0.21 BTC sold with ~$2,750 in return.

Note: Don't tell me to use Bit-MEX, Bitfinex, etc. because I live in the United States.

Comment: Hey Numberphile this post doesn't fit with Bitcoin Stack Overflow. Maybe try your question on a reddit subform such as BitcoinMarkets (strictly as an example) or other discussion forum.